# How to analyse Testcases from src/test/java folder using sonarlint in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testcase, sonarlint-intellij

How to use `sonarlint` for analyzing testcases? I have found similar thing in sonar cube `sonar.test.inclusions` as property but couldn't find anything similar in `sonarlint > intellij.`

Folder I need to analyse: `src/test/java`

**Work around:**

---

Renaming test folder worked for me.I changed test to test1. Is there proper way/steps I can follow and can analyse testcases?

Comment: I believe it not possible as per standards defined by the makers of this plugin. It is not advisable also. https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-and-sonarqube-analysis-on-automation-test-scripts/910

Answer (score 0):

Just change the test/java folder to "Source Root" as follows.
Then restart or disable then enable SonarLint.
I tried it and it works fine.

[image: make folder test to Source]